# Fetch category from custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I bought a Wordpress Theme hoping that after some code customisation it should achieve what I want.

Now, I have (what I believe it is) a custom post type called 'Portofolio'. As you can see in the picture below, it has the portofolio entries (at all portofolio) and categories for the aforementioned portofolio entries.

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is listing on a custom template page all the categories of the portofolio. So far I have this code but all it does is to fetch the entries of the portofolio not the categories.

```
    <?php
//$args = array('post_type' => 'tm_portfolio');
$term_ids = get_terms( 'tm_portfolio_category', ['fields' => 'ids'] );
$args = [
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'tm_portfolio_category',
            'terms' => $term_ids
        ]
    ]
];
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  echo 'List of categories';
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <?php
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```

As you can see in the code, as the first line, I tried to fetch from the custom post type, but I had the same result.

I figured out the name/slug of the post type/taxonomy by checking the link in the admin panel while adding a category (check the picture below).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked too much into the code, but I can see from the start that this line is not right.

```
$term_ids = get_terms( 'tm_portfolio_category', ['fields' => 'ids'] );
```

it should be "id"

e.g.

```
$term_ids = get_terms( 'tm_portfolio_category', ['fields' => 'id'] );
```

**EDIT**

Sorry my bad,

You can try this approach instead

```
$term_ids = get_terms( 'tm_portfolio_category', ['fields' => 'ids'] );

$posts = query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'tm_portfolio',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tm_portfolio_category',
            'terms'    => $term_ids,
            )
        )
    ));

foreach ($posts as $post) {
   echo 'List of categories';
   ?>
   <p><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php echo the_title_attribute(array('post'=>$post->ID)); ?>">
   <?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>
    </a></p>
   <?php
}
wp_reset_query();
```

I would not recommend using the native WordPress Loop in this case for the sake of flexibility.

I have tested this on my end and it seems to be working. You may need to relook at what is returned when you use get_terms as the array that is returned might be indexed in a different way to how the query arguments are recieved.

**EDIT**

Sorry I feel like I keep missing the initial question.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'tm_portfolio_category' );
```

is going to give you a list of terms.

```
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    ?>
    List of categories
    <p>
        <a href="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php echo $term->name ?>" ><?php echo $term->name ?></a>
    </p>
    <?php 
}

?>
```

Below that should give you the desired result without having to create another query.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, unfortunately It still returns the entries and not the categories.

Comment: I will try to explain. As depicted in the first image, I have a (as I said, what I suppose a post type) Portofolio. I am using this to make a relationship between countries and clubs. By adding a new entry to the portofolio (Add new button/All portofolio) I will basically add a Club. All these clubs will be sorted/placed by/into countries (which are in fact the categories).
A tl;dr version will be - a portofolio entry = club. A portofolio category = country.

Comment: Using this $terms = get_terms( 'tm_portfolio_category' ); I managed to query out some of the categories. Somehow I have in Wp 7 categories but on the page it returns 4.

Comment: I managed to show them all by adding hide_empty = false. Final line of code for the terms is $terms = get_terms( 'tm_portfolio_category' , array('hide_empty' => false)); . Thanks a lot :) I should figure out from this point how to query out the links and so on using the codex of wordpress.